# Stop chrome from refreshing not responding page

Tags: google-chrome, sapui5, sap-web-ide

I am currently trying to debug an SAP Fiori Application.

I am launching it via `SAP-WEB-IDE` and I 've set some external breakpoints in my ABAP BackendSystem.

Now for better debugging I've set the `ClientReadTimeout` to a max. of `300000ms` for my Backend-Destination in the Cloud Platform Cockpit.

Now when I hit my breakpoint, I can debug just fine, until Chrome tells me "This site is not responding".

I hit "Wait", but after some amount of time my debugger is suspended and the breakpoint gets hit again.

I guess Chrome did a refresh by itself....

How can I prevent that ?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think chrome refreshed it.

In ABAP there is a timeout set for the debugger (work process in particular), which is stopping your debugger from continuing beyond a set time. You can set this with system parameter rdisp/max_wprun_time. 
You may also look into parameter rdisp/max_debug_lazy_time